# Spring ignores custom ObjectMapper during data binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-rest

I am trying to enable Jackson's "fail on unknown properties" feature for all endpoints in my service. I've added `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig{
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder(){
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new     Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.failOnUnknownProperties(true);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

When I use injected `ObjectMapper`, validation works as supposed, it throws `HttpMessageNotReadableException` while passing invalid json:

```
public class Person{
    @NotNull
    private String name; 
    @NotNull
    private String surname;

    /*getters and setters*/
}

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

Person person = objectMapper.readValue("{ "\unknown\":\"field\", \"name\":\"John\", \"surname\":\"Smith\" }", Person.class);
```

However when i pass same json straight to controller validation does not occur and body of method is invoked:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void something(@Valid @RequestBody Person person){...}
```

Firstly I thought that `MessageConverter` does not use custom `ObjectMapper` so I checked it:

```
@Autowired
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter;

converter.getObjectMapper().getDeserializationConfig().hasDeserializationFeatures(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES.getMask())); 
//returns true
```

It's even more weird because when i use repositories in other part of service validation works in POST method but does not work in PUT method.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "...", path = "...")
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {
    @Override 
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') || hasPermission(#car, T(...).CREATE_OR_MODIFY")
    Car save(@Param("car") Car car);

    /*other methods*/
}
```

Is there a simple way to force controllers and repositories to check if passed json does not contain unknown properties?

Comment: I've lost 3 hours of my life on a similar problem because I had `@EnableWebMvc` on one of my config classes. Make sure you don't.

Comment: I've removed that annotation from my code but it hasn't helped.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot, saved my ass

Answer (score 1):

When working with spring data rest there are multiple ObjectMappers registered in the application context e.g. one for application/hal+json and one for application/json. It looks like spring data rest is not using the primary object mapper that you configured.

If you want to configure the spring data rest object mapper you can do this using a `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.configuration

```
public class DefaultRepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder;

    @Override
    public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

        if (this.objectMapperBuilder != null) {
            this.objectMapperBuilder.configure(objectMapper);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but adding that hasn't changed anything. As i wrote, validation works with repositories and POST requests. It works as well when I do PUT request with invalid id (that doesn't exist in database) but it doesn't throw `HttpMessageNotReadableException` with good id requests. It looks like when authentication passes Spring uses wrong `MessageConverter` / ignores `ObjectMapper` features. And it's not problem only with repositories, controller doesn't work as well.